C# Checking the results of AWS GetObject
When using IAmazonS3.GetObjectAsync() the response includes HttpStatusCode and checksums.
I've look at several examples but none of them are checking the HttpStatusCode or checksum.
Should I verify the results of HttpStatusCode and checksum or does that happen automatically?
If it's automatic what happens if HttpStatusCode is not OK or checksum is not equal? Does it throw an exception and if so what kind of exception?
